# Header style of data grid is not standardize when the data is group by expander

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header, styles, expander

I have a standard style for my data grid header as below.

[image]

When there is data in the data grid, and my data is group by expander, a new column is created and the style of header is not following my data grid style.

[image]

Anyone has idea why the column of expander does not follow my style?

Here is my codes:

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="dataGridResult"
              Grid.Row="1" RowHeight="20"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding ResultList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              BorderBrush="White" 
              IsReadOnly="True" 
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
              Margin="15"
              Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
              GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="180" Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding RunNo}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding TestProgramVersion}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Header="Column3" Binding="{Binding StartTestTime}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Header="Column4" Binding="{Binding EndTestTime}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander x:Name="MyExpander" IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="MyExpanderHeader" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Style

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
     <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF048EC0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

** ===== Updates after try on suggestion by II Vic ===== **

1. Hide "Show All Rows" button - the Data 1 is not align correctly with Column 2

[image]

2. Add style for "Show All Rows" button - doesn't work

[image]

Comment: It is really strange, using the style for the "select all rows" button worked for me. Which framework version are you using? Can you post your XAML, please?

Answer (score 0):

The new column which is created and which has a wrong style, is not a column header. Indeed it is a "select all rows" button (if you click it all the rows are selected).

Since it is not a column header, it does not use the column header style.
You have two options for solving your issue:

1. You can hide the "select all rows" button by setting the `DataGrid` `HeadersVisibility` property to `Column`
2. You can create a style for the "select all rows" button.

It should looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
        x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF048EC0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have tried two of the methods. for the first 1, it hide the "select all rows" button, eventually will cause the data does not align with the header.
2nd approach doesn't work for me.
Please see my updates in OP. Thanks.